# Split VLC Stream Between Processes

Tags: video, vlc, webcam, streaming

I have multiple webcams connected to my computer, which I'm viewing through VLC (using a VLM script and the mosaic module). The script also dumps the camera feeds to a file for testing. This is all working well, and I'm pleased with the results.

Now, I would also like to be able to display one of the camera feeds on a second monitor. Since I want to control this separately, it seems it will need to be a separate instance of VLC.

But unfortunately, v4l2 will not allow two separate processes to read from the same device at the same time. VLM is already duplicating these streams, to show them on the screen and also write them to a file...but I cannot find a way to send that stream *to another process*. I can send it through HTTP, but this adds enormous overhead and over ten seconds of delay. A pipe would be ideal, but the second process would need to somehow discard all the data put into the pipe before it started.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?